# has_secure_password not encrypting my password

Tags: ruby-on-rails, security

I know this question has been asked before but I can't figure out how to solve my problem.

If I follow the tutorial https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/SecurePassword/ClassMethods.html
it says I need a column password_digest in my schema and has_secure_password in the model

Then, in my controller, I use strong params in order to create the instance of the model (my model is not called user though).

It looks like that:

```
@work = Work.find(params[:work_id])
@work_provider = WorkProvider.create(work_provider_params)
@work_provider.work = @work
@provider = Provider.find(params[:provider_id])
@work_provider.provider = @provider
@work_provider.name = @provider.name
@work_provider.category = @provider.category
@work_provider.save

def work_provider_params
    params.require(:work_provider).permit(:name, :category, :email, :password_digest)
  end
```

My email and password_digest being in the strong  params work_provider_params.

Everything works without error... But it's just says blank in the DB. I am using device for users, and when I try to put the user password in the view, it doesn't show because it's encrypted. 
But here, my work_provider password is showing in the view if I try to print it, which makes me think it has not been encrypted!

Thanks for your help!!

Comment: I guess you should allow `password`, not `password_digest` in your `work_provider_params`.

Answer (score 1):

You want to accept the password in plaintext from the user - not the digest which is a hash created from the plaintext.

```
def work_provider_params
  params.require(:work_provider)
        .permit(:name, :category, :email, :password)
end
```

Taking the digest from the params negates the whole purpose of password encryption - the idea is that you never store the plaintext in the DB.

However if you are using Devise there is no point in using `ActiveModel::SecurePassword`. Devise handles this on its own through the database_authenicable module. I would suggest you [follow the instructions for Devise](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise) instead.

Comment: Amazing!!! It works like that,  I changed to password everywhere but kept password_digest in the  db. I am already using Device for my Users and I was thinking it would not  be possible or too complicated to use it again for my work-provider model (the schema is  a bit complicated and the creation  involves scraping and a few things). But secure password  works now!!!!

Comment: Authenticating two different models in devise is not complicated at all though.

Comment: Hi again! Ok I'll check Devise now :) I have another problem now with has_secure_password. I  am using the password I encrypted in order to scrape a website, but it now uses the encrypted password instead of the normal one... Which blocks my account telling me I used  the wrong password too many times.  Is  there a way to tell Rails to use the unencrypted password in order to perform an action?

Comment: No, the point of BCrypt is that it is a one way hash. You can’t get the cleartext back - you can only check if another password generates a matching hash. This is a important security measure so that if your database is compromised your users passwords will not be leaked since people use the same password everywhere. To store third party credentials you need a totally different solution.

Comment: That applies to devise as well as has_secure_password and any password authentication scheme that is not insecure.

Comment: Oh no! Ok, thanks a lot.  Do you have any idea of the direction I should follow in order to store third party credentials? I don't have access to their API's

Comment: Rubys OpenSSL module supports quite a few two encryption algoritms like blowfish. Allthough this whole thing is starting to smell fishy and I would consider if what you’re doing is prudent and legal. It sounds like a pretty blantant violation of the TOS of most services.

Comment: Ok Max thanks, I'll check if it's legal or not.  I know an app that does something similar so I think  that's ok but I will double check!! Thank you :)